# Составления отчета из базы данных по нескольким таблицам

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Как составить отчет по нескольким таблицам? Все записи в таблицы заявки объединяются по году и недели в виде ссылки. На другой страницы производится запрос на выборку всех записей входящих в выбранную(неделю год).
Получается нужен перекрестный запрос, но как его на MySqli и PHP делать не пойму.
Причем на каждую дату должна быть отдельная таблица. То-есть шапка с датой должна быть одна на один день, а все записи что входят в эту дату должны быть в одной таблицы.Вот такого плана отчет, только нужно чтобы данные из бд брались и шапка у таблицы была одна на одну дату.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php

$result_mail5 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `Application`  WHERE YEARWEEK (`Date_event`,1) = '".intval($_GET['id'])."' ORDER BY `Date_event` ASC");
while($object5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mail5))
{
    $sum = strftime("%e %B %Y %A" , strtotime($object5['Date_event']));
    if($object5['ID_Status']==0)
    {
        echo '<style> .p{background:#ff0000;} </style>';
    }
?>
    <div id ="add_container">
     <h4 style="text-transform:uppercase;"> <?php echo $sum; ?> </h4> 
     <table border="1">
   <tr class="p">
    <td>Название  сюжета</td>
    <td>Творческая <br> группа</td>
    <?php 
    $result_mail10 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `Video_camera`");
    while($object10 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_mail10))
    {   
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $object10['Name']; ?></td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td>Оператор<br>Корреспондент</td><>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>12:00<br>16:00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
    </div>
<?php
}   
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<pre> 
Содержимое таблицы  Заявка
ID_Application     ID_Status    ID_Video_camera    ID_Car     Date_event     Time_start_event     Time_end_event      Name_event     Location  
76            1          3           1        2018-01-08    12:00:00             13:00:00          Название       Место
77            1          1           1        2018-01-08    12:00:00         15:00:00          Название       Место
78            1          3           2        2018-01-11    15:00:00         17:00:00          Название       Место

Содержимое таблицы Камера
ID_Video_camera     Name
 1                 DVC 1    
 2                 DVC 2
 3                 DVC 3
...                ...
 16                DVC 16

Содержимое таблицы Сотрудник
ID_Employees      ID_Employee_type     F.I.O
 1                   5                 Капитанов А.Р.
 2                   6                 Попов А.Р.
 3                   5                 Кап А.Р.
 4                   6                 По А.Р.
...                  ...                ...

 Содержимое таблицы Заявка Сотрудникам
 ID_Application   ID_Employees
 76                 1
 76                 3
 76                 5
 77                 1
 77                 3
 77                 5
 ...                ...

Пример результата 
Name_event    F.I.O         DVC 1       DVC 2       DVC 3   ...  DVC 16
Название    Капитанов А.Р.                          12:00
            Кап А.Р.                                13:00
Название    Капитанов А.Р.   12:00
            Кап А.Р.         15:00


<code>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Добавьте пример содержимого таблицы и пример результата. Тогда у вас появятся шансы получить ответ.

Comment: В mysql - отсортируйте по дате, в php - на каждой итерации цикла в конце записываете дату текущей строчки в переменную, в начале - проверяете, совпадает ли текущая с последней записанной. Если различаются - выводите заголовок. Самое муторное (не сложное, а именно муторное) это вывод открывающих/закрывающих тегов таблицы.